# Automatically concatenate all columns with delimiter

Tags: postgresql

i have table "Custommers" :

```
 ID   Code Name
 1    10   Marry
```

i want get result is:

```
  1^10^Marry
```

but I don't want to name each column explicitly like this:

```
select ID||^||Code||^Name 
from Customers
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Me to use PostgreSQL 8.3.it not error.but i want not using it.i want using auto .i have sql get column in table :select column_name 
from 
 information_schema.columns 
 where table_schema='medibv_vn' and table_name='Customers'

Comment: Me to use PostgreSQL 8.3.it not error.but i want not using it.i want using auto .i have sql get column in table :select column_name 
from 
 information_schema.columns 
 where table_schema='medibv_vn' and table_name='Customers'.i want not write  column name into select.i want it auto get column name and get value.please,Thanks!

Comment: You just changed your question to mean something totally different. Please post a new question for a new problem. I have reversed your change.

Answer (score 1):

About your only option is:

```
COPY Customers TO stdout WITH DELIMITER '^' CSV;
```

so that should help you out until you can upgrade. You can specify only a subset of columns to `COPY` or `COPY` from a `(SELECT ...)` query if you don't want the whole table, eg:

```
COPY Customers("ID") TO stdout WITH DELIMITER '^' CSV;
```

or

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE "ID" <> 4) TO stdout WITH DELIMITER '^' CSV;
```

Not all client drivers support `COPY`. This will work from `psql` but not PgJDBC, for example. Some drivers (like PgJDBC) provide their own API that let you use `COPY` indirectly. See the manual for your driver for information on using the `COPY` command.

A very ugly alternative that doesn't require `COPY` support is:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(replace(Customers::text,',','^'), '\((.*)\)'))[1] FROM Customers;
```

but this will turn *any* comma into a `^`, so if your `Name` field contains `Doe, John` you'll get `Doe^ John` as output - probably not what you want. Pg will quote fields that contain commas, but the replace won't respect that quoting. You might be able to come up with a `regexp_replace` expression that'll do it if you try hard enough; you'll have to handle the case of a literal `"` in the string (resulting in `""` in the output) too. See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/9c2d0/1).

---

I originally thought you might've just been trying to get rid of the `||` operators, in which case this would've helped if you weren't using an such an old version of PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT concat_ws('^', "ID", "Code", "Name") FROM Customers;
```

Also, note that the COPY syntax above is the obsolete style. New code on modern PostgreSQL versions should be using:

```
COPY Customers TO stdout WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '^')
```

instead. This will not work for you on 8.3, it's too old.

Comment: @user2281426 Glad to help. Please mark as accepted when the timer will let you; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  . Also, **start planning to upgrade from 8.3 to a supported version**, especially if you want to ask others for help; you'll get lots of answers that don't work on your version.

Comment: i used :COPY Customers TO stdout WITH DELIMITER '^' CSV;but it run forever,not stop. you can help me?Thanks!.i using postgres 8.3

Comment: @user2281426 Using which client? `psql`? If you `COPY ... TO '/tmp/test.csv'` does that finish, and if so does a `/tmp/test.csv` file appear on the *server* ?