# Convert one row to array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, row

I have table:

```
Id Code Name
1  001  Marry
```

I want this result:

```
{1,001,Marry}
```

Comment: I suggested you post a *detailed* question when you followed this up. This is not a helpful or detailed question. You haven't even explained what you said in the previous question or linked to it! You didn't even include your PostgreSQL version despite explicitly being reminded to. Also, please format your questions; see the help link when writing questions. Close-voted. Please read the FAQ on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Tip: `SELECT x::text FROM mytable x;` . See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/9c2d0/2, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/9c2d0/1

Comment: BTW, if you were on a modern PostgreSQL version you could use the `json` support in 9.2.

Comment: i used suscessful sql.thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Use an [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT ARRAY[Id::text, Code::text, Name::text] AS my_arr FROM tbl;
```

We need a common type, of course. Array element have to be of the same type. Every type can be cast to `text`, so it's the obvious choice here.

Comment: I want not write Id,Code,Name. I want it will get all column of one row into array .i have sql get all column of table is:select column_name
from  
 information_schema.columns 
where 
 table_schema='medibv_vn' 
 and table_name='icd10'.now,i want in array show all column in one row.thanks.

Comment: @user2281426: All of this should be in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Some context is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009061/automatically-concatenate-all-columns-with-delimiter

Comment: @user2281426: I think I answered the question asked correctly. You need to write a proper question. Be clear what you want. An *array* or a *concatenated string with separators*? If you want all columns without naming them, this has to be in the question, obviously. You have been asked to clarify your question before. It is impolite to waste the time of people trying to help.